# How to check if value inside of json and get the object that contains the keys with that value?

Tags: python, json

I have this JSON object

```
{'result': 
     {'chk_in': '2022-05-28', 
      'chk_out': '2022-05-30', 
      'currency': 'USD', 
      'rates': [
            {'code': 'Expedia', 'name': 'Expedia', 'rate': 299.0, 'tax': 70.0}, 
            {'code': 'BookingCom', 'name': 'Booking.com', 'rate': 299.0, 'tax': 73.0},
            {'code': 'CtripTA', 'name': 'Trip.com', 'rate': 297.0, 'tax': 66.0}, 
               ], 
}
```

How do I check and get the keys 'code' inside 'rates' contain value 'Expedia'?

This is what I tried but did not succeed.

```
if ('code','Expedia') in json_object['result']['rates'].items():
            print(json_object['result']['rates'])
        else:
            print('no price')
```

Comment: `json_object['result']['rates']` is a `list`, not a `dict`.

Answer (score 2):

`json_object['result']['rates']` is a list, not a dict, so it doesn't have an `items()` method.  What you want is something like:

```
[rate for rate in json_object['result']['rates'] if rate['code'] == 'Expedia']
```

This will give you a list of all the dictionaries in `rates` matching the criteria you're looking for; there might be none, one, or more.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the data inside the "rates" key is a list. Take a look at the following:

```
>>> data = {'result':
     {'chk_in': '2022-05-28',
      'chk_out': '2022-05-30',
      'currency': 'USD',
      'rates': [
            {'code': 'Expedia', 'name': 'Expedia', 'rate': 299.0, 'tax': 70.0},
            {'code': 'BookingCom', 'name': 'Booking.com', 'rate': 299.0, 'tax': 73.0},
            {'code': 'CtripTA', 'name': 'Trip.com', 'rate': 297.0, 'tax': 66.0},
               ],
}}
>>> type(data["result"]["rates"])
<class 'list'>
```

I'm not sure if I understand what you're trying to do *exactly* but maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
>>> data["result"]["rates"]
[{'code': 'Expedia', 'name': 'Expedia', 'rate': 299.0, 'tax': 70.0}, {'code': 'BookingCom', 'name': 'Booking.com', 'rate': 299.0, 'tax': 73.0}, {'code': 'CtripTA', 'name': 'Trip.com', 'rate': 297.0, 'tax': 66.0}]
>>> for rate in data["result"]["rates"]:
...     code = rate["code"]
...     if code == "Expedia":
...             print(rate)
...
{'code': 'Expedia', 'name': 'Expedia', 'rate': 299.0, 'tax': 70.0}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to look through the list of rates and seach the ones with `el['code'] == 'Expedia'` :

```
d = {'result': 
     {'chk_in': '2022-05-28', 
      'chk_out': '2022-05-30', 
      'currency': 'USD', 
      'rates': [
            {'code': 'Expedia', 'name': 'Expedia', 'rate': 299.0, 'tax': 70.0}, 
            {'code': 'BookingCom', 'name': 'Booking.com', 'rate': 299.0, 'tax': 73.0},
            {'code': 'CtripTA', 'name': 'Trip.com', 'rate': 297.0, 'tax': 66.0}, 
               ], 
}
     }
     
     
print([el for el in d['result']['rates'] if el['code']=='Expedia'])


>>> [{'code': 'Expedia', 'name': 'Expedia', 'rate': 299.0, 'tax': 70.0}]
```